# check if git commit is in the current working tree

Tags: git, jenkins

i was wondering if there is a git command to see if a specific commit is in the current working tree. I have the shasign of the specific commit. I like to know if this commit is a commit done by another user in another working tree or if it's commit which is newer then the current HEAD of my working tree.

The reason i want to do this is, because we have a Jenkins server set up and there are builds done regularly, but i want to test the latest build to see if it's the same as my HEAD, or if it's an older commit, or if it's a commit done by someone else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think by "in the current working tree" you must mean "in the history of HEAD".

To do the tests you describe, given the SHA1sum `S`, you can do the following:

- To see if `S` is the same as your `HEAD`, compare `git rev-parse --verify S` with `git rev-parse --verify HEAD`
- Otherwise, to see if it's a commit in the history of `HEAD`, you can compare `git merge-base S HEAD` with `git rev-parse --verify S`.  If they are the same, then `S` is an ancestor of `HEAD`.
- To see if it's a commit "done by someone else", you need to compare the authors of the two commits, which you could do by comparing `git show -s --pretty='%an <%ae>' HEAD` and `git show -s --pretty='%an <%ae>' S`